# VBscript XMLHTTP get web page returns blank

Tags: vbscript

I am attempting to merge parts of several wiki pages to create a condensed/summarized version.
The following code works for pages like google.com.
But, it's returning a blank result for the page I want.

Any suggestions?

```
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
o.open "GET", "http://stevescarts2.wikispaces.com/Modules", False
o.send
If err.number = 0 then    
    MsgBox o.responseText
Else
    MsgBox "error " & err.number & ": " & err.description
End If
```

Comment: I don't know what the limits are for new users, but if you can, you should add your final code as another answer and remove it from the question. You can still give a nod to Ansgar and leave the checkmark on his answer. This just keeps questions as questions and answers as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no response text. The server responds with status [`302 Found`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to that request. **Always** check the status when dealing with XMLHTTP requests:

```
WScript.Echo o.status & " " & o.statusText
```

Comment: But that url shows fine in a browser. How do I get the source?

Comment: Fixed it :)    
Thanks for pointing me to status (which led me to the responseheader)

Comment: Thanks, Ansgar. Im a newbie to stackoverflow. I'm having trouble formatting in comments. In 4(!) hours I'll post the modified code that works for me. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sheesh. I keep missing the 5 minute edit window :) I've inserted the modified code that works for me in the original post. Thanks again, Ansgar :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Ansgar.
Much appreciated.
Here's the modified code that works for me...

```
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
url = "http://stevescarts2.wikispaces.com/Modules"
Do
  o.open "GET", url, False
  o.send
  If o.Status = 302 Then
    url = o.GetResponseHeader("Location")
  End If
Loop Until err.number = 0 And o.Status <> 302
If err.number = 0 then  
  MsgBox o.responseText
ElseIf o.status & " " & o.statusText Then
  MsgBox "error " & err.number & ": " & err.description
End If
```